# How to remove double quotes from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Say I have the array below

```
var someStuff = [
  "start", { one: "one"},
  "setSomething", "foobar",
  "someBool", true
];
```

How can I transform it to be as below

```
var someStuff = [
  MainFunc.start({one: "one"}),
  MainFunc.setClientId('foobar'),
  MainFunc.someBool(true)
];
```

Comment: What is MainFunc?

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you not make a proper object of someStuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want an array containing results from a number of function calls, this is how you can get that. You need to iterate over the array, get each function from the MainFunc object and then call that each time.

I included handling for a non-existing function being called, which happened to be in your example (perhaps not intentional).

```js
var MainFunc = {
  start       : function(x) { return "start called with " + x.toString(); },
  setClientId : function(x) { return "setClientId called with " + x.toString(); },
  someBool    : function(x) { return "someBool called with " + x.toString(); }
}

var someStuff = [
  "start", { one: "one" },
  "setSomething", "foobar",
  "setClientId", "foobar",
  "someBool", true
];

var result = Process(someStuff);

function Process(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    let fnToCall = MainFunc[arr[i]];
    let fnResult = fnToCall ? fnToCall(arr[i + 1]) : "(unknown: '" + arr[i] + "')";
    result.push(fnResult);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (You need to use arrow functions because otherwise the function would get called straigh away):

```js
var someStuff = [
  "start", { one: "one"},
  "setSomething", "foobar",
  "someBool", true
];

let output = []

for(let i=0, j=0; i<someStuff.length; i+=2, j++) {
  let functionName = someStuff[i];
  let functionArgs = someStuff[i+1];

  output[j] = () => MainFunc[functionName](functionArgs);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to do this

```js
function mainFunc() {
  this.start = function(obj) { console.log("start",obj) };
  this.setSomething = function(obj) { console.log("set",obj) };
  this.someBool =     function(obj) { console.log("bool",obj) };
}

var someStuff = {
  "start": { "one":"one"},
  "setSomething": "foobar",
  "someBool": true
}; 
var mf = new mainFunc();
for (var a in someStuff) {
  mf[a](someStuff[a])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better readability, define an array of objects with action and its parameter.

```
const mainFunc = {
  start: (param) => console.log('start', param),
  setSomething: (param) => console.log('SetSomething', param),
  someBool: (param) => console.log('someBool', param)
}

var someStuff = [   
  { action: "start", param: { one: "one"} },
  { action: "setSomething", param: "foobar" },
  { action: "someBool",  param: true }
];

someStuff.forEach(stuff => {
    if (typeof mainFunc[stuff.action] === 'function') {
      mainFunc[stuff.action](stuff.param);
    }
});
```